# How to group data for every person separately in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a base class:

```
public class Base  
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
   public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}
}
```

and get the current list data:

- **Name**: Person1, **StartDate**:27/12/2016, **EndDate**:28/12/2016
- **Name**: Person2, **StartDate**:21/12/2016, **EndDate**:22/12/2016
- **Name**: Person2, **StartDate**:17/12/2016, **EndDate**:20/12/2016
- **Name**: Person1, **StartDate**:21/11/2017, **EndDate**:22/11/2017

So I divided it into two classes:

```
public class Person 
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public List<PersonDates> Dates {get;set}
}

public class PersonDates 
{
     public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
     public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}
}
```

My problem is that I want to have list of dates for every person.

How can I do that with Entity Framework lambda expressions, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the `Base` objects from database separatly, group them separatly.

```
bases
.GroupBy(x=>x.Name)
.Select(x=>
    new Person
    {
        Name =x.Key, 
        PersonDates = x.Select(
                y=>new PersonDates{
                StartDate=y.StartDate, 
                EndDate =y.EndDate})
            .ToList()
    }
);
```